# Magento 2 Hide 'Skip to the beginning of the images gallery'

Tags: magento2

I want to hide the 'Skip to the beginning of the images gallery' message from the product details page.
I will always have only single image for all products so I need to hide the message.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to add below two line in your `catalog_product_view.xml` file inside body tags in your theme

```
<referenceContainer name="skip_gallery_before.wrapper" remove="true" />
<referenceContainer name="skip_gallery_after.wrapper" remove="true" />
```

Or create new file in your theme here

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="skip_gallery_before.wrapper" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="skip_gallery_after.wrapper" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

After adding above 2 lines please clear Magento cache using below commands :

> php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush

Hope this will help you!